# Rails 3 generating json file to use it in javascript library - D3.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, graph, d3.js

I'm new with rails, and i'm trying to integrate d3.js javascript library with.

How can i generate a .json file with db data and then using it in a method call like

```
d3.json("miserables.json", function(json) {
                    var force = self.force = d3.layout.force()
                    .nodes(json.nodes)
                    .links(json.links)
```

i need somehow to create miserables.json to drawn one graph and then invoking `d3.json` method

Thanks in advance
Joao

Answer (score 1):

Try the [json gem](http://flori.github.com/json/).